# IdentityServer3 Invalid_grant when retrieving access token after expiration

Tags: identityserver3

When performing an ajax call into my MVC application more than 5 minutes after my AccessTokenLifetime, the ClaimsPrincipal value for access_token is null.

I have tried RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync and RequestRefreshTokenAsync, using cached values of code & redirect_uri, and refresh_token respectively, but these calls both return an invalid_grant error.  Our openId-configuration does list authorization_code and refresh_token under grant_types_supported.  I have tried running this code before timeout, and I get the same error for both calls.

Is the fact that the request is coming in from javascript preventing me from getting a new access code?  Thanks in advance for your consideration and help

Here are some samples of my setup:

---

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
});
```

---

```
app.Map("/js", api =>
{
    api.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = Constants.IdentityServerUrl,
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "scope1", "offline_access" },
        ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Both
    });
});
```

---

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
{
    var client = new TokenClient(
        Identity.Constants.TokenEndpoint,
        Identity.Constants.IdentityClientId,
        Identity.Constants.IdentityClientSecret);
    var tokenResponse = client.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken).Result;
```

Identity Server Logs

> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - REQUEST
>   GET /api/users
>       Request URL: local-urlcode: 401Server response time: 15.26 msRequest URL base: /api/users
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Secret validator success: {0}
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   End token request
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Returning error: invalid_grant
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start token request validation
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Invalid authorization code: f2e8a4ce0eef941ab883344559a7183e { "ClientId": "identitymgmt", "ClientName": "Identity Management", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "AuthorizationCode": "f2e8a4ce0eef941ab883344559a7183e", "...
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Client validation success
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:59 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start validation of authorization code token request
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start token request
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Parser found secret: {0}
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   No secret in post body found
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Secret id found: {0}
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   client_id is not found in post body
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start parsing for X.509 certificate
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start client validation
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start parsing for secret in post body
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - REQUEST
>   POST /core/connect/token
>   Request URL: http :// [idp-server-address] /core/connect/tokenResponse code: 400Server response time: 23.62 msRequest URL base: /core/connect/token
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   End token request
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Returning error: invalid_grant
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Invalid authorization code: f2e8a4ce0eef941ab883344559a7183e { "ClientId": "identitymgmt", "ClientName": "Identity Management", "GrantType": "authorization_code", "AuthorizationCode": "f2e8a4ce0eef941ab883344559a7183e", "...
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start validation of authorization code token request
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start token request validation
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Secret validator success: {0}
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Client validation success
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Parser found secret: {0}
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Secret id found: {0}
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start parsing for secret in post body
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   No secret in post body found
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   client_id is not found in post body
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start parsing for X.509 certificate
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start client validation
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - CUSTOM EVENT
>   Start token request
>   Device type: PC
>
> 9/26/2016, 2:30:58 PM - REQUEST
>   POST /core/connect/token
>   Request URL: http: // [idp-server-address] /core/connect/tokenResponse code: 400Server response time: 584.15 msRequest URL base: /core/connect/token

Comment: Does your IdentityServer configuration have the offline_access scope set for your client? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385593/identity-server-not-returning-refresh-token

Comment: My client does have offline_access scope in ScopeRestrictions.  Thanks for the link.  I do have a refresh token: I'm unable to use it to get a new access_token.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the IdSrv3 logs to see what is causing the invalid_grant error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're having a similar problem.